# Hölder's inequality for Hilbert-Schmidt operators which are also trace class

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Do Hilbert-Schmidt operators which are also trace class, satisfy Hölder's inequality? That is, we have two Hilbert-Schmidt operators $A$ and $B$. Is the following true?
$$\langle A, B \rangle \leq \lVert A \rVert_p \lVert B \rVert_q $$

when $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Specifically, is it true for $p=1$, $q=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, this is standard stuff. Note that any trace class operator belongs to all the Schatten $p$-spaces. We do have a Holder inequality. In fact, if $A$ is trace class and $B$ is any bounded operator then $|tr(AB^*)| \leq \|A\|_1 \|B\|$. You should be able to find this in most textbooks.

Comment: (I assume you mean $|\langle A, B\rangle|$, not $\langle A,B\rangle$.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I mean $|<A,B>|$. Can you point me to a reference (textbook, paper)?

Comment: Probably in Dunford-Schwartz, likely in Conway. The $p=1$, $q = \infty$ inequality is in chapter 6 of my book *Mathematical Quantization*.